# Recover registered servers in SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

My computer died so it's be reinstalled.

Previously I had SQL Server 2008 R2 installed. On the new system I have SQL Server 2012.

I have the old `RegSrvr.xml` file (that contains the list of registered SQL Servers).

How do I get the server list from 2008 R2 into 2012?

**Update:**
When doing  Local Server Groups -> Tasks -> Import and choose the `RegSrvr.xml` file, click OK it's says "The import was successfull" - but no servers or folders has been added and the `RegSrvr.xml` file for the 2012 installation has not been modified

**Sample from xml file**

```
 <document>
  <docinfo>
    <aliases>
      <alias>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/DatabaseEngineServerGroup/ServerGroup/Company1/RegisteredServer/stage</alias>
    </aliases>
    <sfc:version DomainVersion="1" />
  </docinfo>
  <data>
    <RegisteredServers:RegisteredServer xmlns:RegisteredServers="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/RegisteredServers/2007/08" xmlns:sfc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08" xmlns:sml="http://schemas.serviceml.org/sml/2007/02" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <RegisteredServers:Parent>
        <sfc:Reference sml:ref="true">
          <sml:Uri>/RegisteredServersStore/ServerGroup/DatabaseEngineServerGroup/ServerGroup/Company1</sml:Uri>
        </sfc:Reference>
      </RegisteredServers:Parent>
      <RegisteredServers:Name type="string">stage.server.dk</RegisteredServers:Name>
      <RegisteredServers:Description type="string" />
      <RegisteredServers:ServerName type="string">stage.server.dk</RegisteredServers:ServerName>
      <RegisteredServers:UseCustomConnectionColor type="boolean">false</RegisteredServers:UseCustomConnectionColor>
      <RegisteredServers:CustomConnectionColorArgb type="int">-986896</RegisteredServers:CustomConnectionColorArgb>
      <RegisteredServers:ServerType type="ServerType">DatabaseEngine</RegisteredServers:ServerType>
      <RegisteredServers:ConnectionStringWithEncryptedPassword type="string">server=stage.server.dk;uid=username;password=AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHoAwE/Cl+sBAAAAegY4QOvPGEGcK2Xdr+jDjQQAAAACAAAAAAADZgAAwAAAABAAAADesdxAGO4GO879z1yS2DZeAAAAAASAAACgAAAAEAAAAGAvgtRJfPRL/puHnREmKu8YAAAAUxRIQVDZHywb7rOYL9MRqG0B2Jvi8kyfFAAAANs53tVPbVux2j56oRU/2oGtmQc9;pooling=false;packet size=4096;multipleactiveresultsets=false</RegisteredServers:ConnectionStringWithEncryptedPassword>
      <RegisteredServers:CredentialPersistenceType type="CredentialPersistenceType">PersistLoginNameAndPassword</RegisteredServers:CredentialPersistenceType>
    </RegisteredServers:RegisteredServer>
  </data>
</document>
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190711.aspx

Comment: @DavidBrabant Tried that already - updated question

Comment: Could you show your RegSrvr.xml file? Is there a  "password=....;" part of the <RegisteredServers:ConnectionStringWithEncryptedPassword>?

Comment: For those servers that doesn't use windows authentication there is a "password=...;" part

Comment: You might find a track to fix your problem here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/de2ee8c4-8d39-45f3-bffd-d31822ab94aa

Comment: That post solved my problem. Solution was do manually edit the xml file and set all servers to use windows authentication - THANKS @DavidBrabant

Comment: Alway happy to help. Posting it as an answer for future SO searches.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your RegSrvr.xml contains a  `"password=....;"` in `<RegisteredServers:ConnectionStringWithEncryptedPassword>` section, replace `";uid=...;password=...;"` with `";trusted_connection=true;"`

In the same file, replace:

```
<RegisteredServers:CredentialPersistenceType type="CredentialPersistenceType">PersistLoginNameAndPassword</RegisteredServers:CredentialPersistenceType>
```

with:

```
<RegisteredServers:CredentialPersistenceType type="CredentialPersistenceType">PersistLoginName</RegisteredServers:CredentialPersistenceType>
```

Now the server registration will try to use Windows Authentication.  Once the Registered Servers are loaded, you can go back and edit the registrations to use your SQL Authentication information.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to the above answer.  Another solution that was easier to use is this :

[Importing registered servers](https://web.archive.org/web/20160117134037/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckwoody/archive/2008/08/18/importing-sql-server-2005-registered-servers-to-sql-server-2008.aspx)

1. On the SQL Server 2005 system, shut down SSMS and copy out the files in this location: “%appdata%\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Shell\RegSrvr.xml”
2. Now copy those files to the same location where you installed SQL Server 2008.
3. Open SSMS 2008 and right-click Local Server Groups  in the Registered Servers window
   Choose Tasks | Previously Registered Servers

For 2014, after I replaced the RegSrvr.xml file with my 2012 copy and launched SSMS, all of the registered servers reappeared without using the **Previously Registered Servers** task.